# Deploy automatico Bitbucket - PHP

Tags: php, git, deploy, bitbucket

Estou tentando usar o Deploy automatico do BitBucket via WebHook para a minha aplicação.
Minha aplicação é PHP usando plataforma Laravel.
Bom, até então estou seguindo esse tutorial:
http://www.cogumello.com/programacao/como-fazer-deploy-automatico-com-bitbucket/comment-page-1/#comment-5424

Fiz tudo conforme o tutorial, porém, a minha aplicação não esta sendo atualizada.

Nos logs do WebHook do Bitbucket está o resultado de Sucesso, ou seja chamou corretamente a minha URL, dentro dos Logs gerados da minha aplicação está a mensagem de sucesso, ou seja, executou tudo correto, porém a aplicação nao atualizou...

Já não sei o que fazer mais..

Comment: Caso queira tentar uma outra abordagem, veja esse [tutorial](https://medium.com/@luisdalmolin/como-fazer-deploy-de-uma-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-laravel-em-uma-hospedagem-compartilhada-bc114ee2cbb9). Não é 100% automático, mas apenas realizar o comando `git push` já é bem prático.

Você pode também dar uma olhada no [Laravel Envoy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/envoy) caso ache que o problema é no script php.

Comment: Opa e ai Vinicius, eu tinha visto essa já, muita coisa pra fazer achei confusa... Essa que citei é bem simples, aparentemente funciona.. problema é que no meu caso não está atualizando o branch.. hahahahah

Answer (score 2):

Sei que a pergunta é antiga mas, atualmente é possível fazer deploy automatizado via `bitbucket-pipelines` usando em conjunto com o `git-ftp`. Basta ativar no seu repositório para usar e configurar seu bitbucket-pipelines.yml com o build. Seria algo como:

```
image: samueldebruyn/debian-git

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
       script:
        - apt-get update
        - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
        - git ftp push --user $FTP_USERNAME --passwd $FTP_PASSWORD ftp://$FTP_HOST
```

Você pode testar a sintaxe do seu [pipeline yml aqui](https://bitbucket-pipelines.prod.public.atl-paas.net/validator).

Comment: Amigo, pode postar um passo a passo de como fazer? Estou querendo integrar o deploy automático em um servidor windows.

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo, basicamente o pipeline do bitbucket é um manuscrito do mesmo processo que você executa para subir seus arquivos no seu servidor. O diferencial é que ele monta tipo uma máquina virtual (no exemplo acima um debian) e executa algum processo. Para deploy via FTP talvez vc queira instalar nessa maquina virtual um ncftp, scp ou git ftp Dê uma olhada [nesse link](http://deevo.com.br/pt/blog/deploy-com-bitbucket-pipeline/) explicando a instalação via git-ftp